# Send object to child template in {% include %} tag in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How can I send list or object to sub template while including template?

```
{% include "subtpl.html" with parameter={"name":"Saifullah","address":"Lahore"} %}
```

When I run the above code I get

```
TemplateSyntaxError Could not parse the remainder: '{"name":"Saifullah","address":"Lahore"}' from '{"name":"Saifullah","address":"Lahore"}'
```

Comment: You can already use that parameter in the `subtpl.html` with `{{parameter.name}}` or if you want in a `for loop` if you include `subtpl.html` in the template that is getting rendered.

Comment: I want {{parameter.name}} in subtpl.html

Comment: You don't need to send that parameter with the `include` then. Just use `{{parameter.name}}` in `subtpl.html`.  As that .html gets included in the template in which you render `parameter`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with Django templates.

You can pass the object if you add it to the template context in the view, for example:

```
def my_view(request):
    parameter = {"name":"Saifullah","address":"Lahore"}
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'parameter': parameter}

{% include "subtpl.html" with parameter=parameter %}
```

Or you could unpack the dictionary and use multiple keyword arguments.

```
{% include "subtpl.html" with name="Saifullah" address="Lahore" %}
```